# Git export/import commits history

Tags: git, repository, export, gitlab, devops

I will try to be as simple as possible...

lets go:

we have one big git repo, which includes 3 folders for different projects:

**Folders structure in main repo:**

```
existing_repo
      ├── .net_is_dir
      ├── java_is_dir
      └── android_is_dir
```

for java, per one issue, we have branch in root

for android dir, per one issue, we have inherited branch in branch "android". In gitlab structure is next:

**Branches structure in repo**

```
existing_repo
      ├── .net_dev
      ├── .net_qa
      |
      ├── java_dev
      ├── java_qa
      ├── java_issue_1
      ├── java_issue_n
      |
      ├── android_dev
      ├── android_qa
      └── android
           ├─ android_issue_1
           └─ android_issue_n
```

task is text:

- I need create 3 new repos for 3 different projects
- .net_newrepo
- java_newrepo
- android_newrepo
- Files, for each project, should be in root (it for CI), not in subdirs.
- Branches should be exported/imported in right way:

  issue1_4_java --> java_newrepo/issue1_4_java

  android/issue1_4_android --> android_newrepo/issue1_4_android
- New project should contain history only about particular project.
  .net about .net, and not about ios and android etc.

I think it is unreal
my workaraunds are

1) import existing repo in new particular repo, move dirs, and delete un useful --> leads to:

each project will contain all old projects, repo will be big

2) create new repos with needed branches, just copy files from appropriare dirs to new branches and commit --> leads to

no history, repo size is small

probably you will suggest me some new ideas?

Comment: Just a wild idea: have overlapping repositories, then run a script that checks each commit in one and commits it to the other one.

Comment: good point! I will think on it

Comment: I mean, it's definitely possible, but maybe there is a better way to do this. If you go for this way, please do share the script you make.

Comment: offcourse I will share it)

Answer (score 1):

Let us try something. It is a bit experimental and will require you jumping in. Excuse me for using "dotnet" instead of ".net" in the following.

```
$ cp -r existing_repo dotnet_newrepo # Get a copy of the existing repo. The new directory will ultimately be the repo for dotnet.
$ cd dotnet_newrepo # Go to the new directory for dotnet.
$ git remote rm origin # Remove the "origin" remote. Do this for all remotes.
$ cd .. # Go back.
$ cp -r dotnet_newrepo java_newrepo # Get a copy for java (without remotes).
$ cp -r dotnet_newrepo android_newrepo # Get a copy for android (without remotes).
```

Now you have three git repos, "dotnet_newrepo", "java_newrepo", "android_newrepo", that are exactly like your existing repo, only without remotes. Moving on.

```
$ cd dotnet_newrepo
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dotnet_is_dir -- --all
$ cd ..
$ cd java_newrepo
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter java_is_dir -- --all
$ cd ..
$ cd android_newrepo
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter android_is_dir -- --all
$ cd ..
```

Each `git filter-branch` command above will go through all (because of `--all`) branches of the repo and rewrite their history, but...

> Only look at the history which touches the given subdirectory. The
>   result will contain that directory (and only that) as its project
>   root.

(from [git-filter-branch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch))

In other words, the contents of the subdirectory will go to the repo's root directory and git history will be rewritten so that it will contain only the history that is relevant to that subdirectory, whose contents will ultimately be the root directory's new and only contents.

Following the steps described above, you should still have all branches (all with rewritten history) in each repo. For each repo you should delete irrelevant branches and rename relevant branches according to your new conventions. If the number of branches is really big, you could use a script for this. Finally, after fixing your branches for each new repo and after creating a corresponding remote repo (e.g. in GitLab), you could add it as a remote and push at will.

Answer (score 0):

seems like problem solved by using commands

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter android_is_dir -- --all
```

thank you @xnakos for you patience. Also, during this I renamed branches, using special keys (googled it) and each new branch I pushed separately, it looks awesome now, dev team will be happy tomorrow)))

BTW till the 3AM night I made script, by it did not work, I see all history per each branch, by I did not see relations between branches (merges)

probably someone will find it interesting,
script is full of crutches and hardcode, but anyway, it worked for me)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import json
import shutil
import subprocess
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

old_repo = "/home/ostetsia/coding/java"
old_repo_dir = "/home/ostetsia/coding/java/java_subdir"
new_repo = "/home/ostetsia/coding/java

old_repo_branch = "java/java_case_number"
new_repo_branch = "java_case_number"

#changing branch in new repo
os.chdir(new_repo)

try:
    subprocess.check_output(["git", "branch", new_repo_branch])
except:
    print "branch {0} exist in new repo".format(new_repo_branch)

subprocess.check_output(["git", "checkout", new_repo_branch])

os.chdir(old_repo)

try:
    subprocess.check_output(["git", "branch", old_repo_branch])
except:
    print "branch {0} exist in old repo".format(old_repo_branch)

os.chdir(old_repo)
subprocess.check_output(["git", "checkout", old_repo_branch])


git_add = "git add *"
git_old_log = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'log', '--reverse', '--pretty=format:{"hash": "%H", "reporter":"%an", "mail": "%ce", "date": "%cd", "comment": "%s"}'])
commit_list = {}

i=0
for data_line in git_old_log.split('\n'):
    i+=1
    data_line = json.loads(data_line)
    commit_list[i] = dict(data_line)

git_old_log_count_commint = i


for commit, data in commit_list.iteritems():

    for key, value in data.iteritems():

        if key == "date":
            date=value
            print date
        elif key == "mail":
            mail = value
        elif key == "hash":
            hash = value
        elif key == "comment":
            comment = value
        elif key == "reporter":
            reporter = value

    git_commit_command = "git commit -a --author='{0} <{1}>' --date='{2}' -am '{3}'".format(reporter, mail, date, comment)
    #print git_commit_command

    os.chdir(new_repo)
    os.system("pwd")
    os.system("rm -rf")
    print commit
    os.chdir(old_repo)
    subprocess.check_output(["git", "checkout", hash])


    copy_tree(old_repo_dir, new_repo)

    os.chdir(new_repo)
    os.system(git_add)
    os.system(git_commit_command)
    print os.getcwd()
```